# Too Many Burn Cards

Tags: rules

This happened last night at a home game. There were 4 players in the hand. Burn card, flop as normal. Betting action which included one player folding. During the action the dealer apparently had burned a card and waited for action to complete. Then, once it was complete, the dealer accidentally burned another card and placed the following card for the turn. The 3 remaining players checked and the dealer placed another card on burn pile but had not exposed the river when I pointed out there were too many burn cards (which was separated from the muck so it was clear but unnoticed to that point, I was not in the hand). Huge debate followed and it was ultimately decided by the 3 players remaining that they wanted the card that was supposed to be the turn to replace the card that was originally shown as the turn. They agreed that the incorrectly exposed turn was to be placed back in the deck and shuffled prior to the placing of the river card. It was also agreed that there would be no more action. I disagreed with that solution but it wasn't my game and I wasn't in the hand. I have played many, many games in various casinos but have not witnessed an issue where too many burns were discovered that late. I did argue that the original turn should remain since action ensued, even though there were no bets made. I would like to know a definitive answer in this case and if anyone has experienced a similar mistake in a casino and how it was resolved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a home game, the rules are those agreed by the players. Anyway it's not probably a good idea to return the burned cards to the deck, and just proceed to deal the next card.

Answer (score 1):

Casino dealers are trained to follow very specific procedures to prevent this kind of thing, but mistakes do happen. A floorman should always be called if an error occurs, and he will make whatever ruling is fairest to the players, with guidance from some standard principles:

1. Once significant betting action takes place after exposing a card, it must stand. That is, if an incorrect turn card (for example) is shown, and there's a bet and call before this is discovered, the card must stay and play continue.
2. If a card is exposed before betting action is complete on the previous round (for example, the last player on the flop has not called and the turn card is exposed), that card cannot play. If it was the turn the dealer should turn the card that would have been the river, then reshuffle the stub and continue.
3. If the error is discovered before betting action, the card should be replaced by the correct one if possible. If this is not possible, then play should be continued in a fair manner determined by the floorman.
4. As always, the floorman has discretion to take any other action he deems necessary to protect the game.

In a home game, substitute "floorman" with "player consensus".